# CSS Background will not stretch 100%

Tags: html, css, background, margin, contact-form

I'm using CSS gradient backgrounds all over my site - I can not get the one for the 'Contact' section to fit right across the page. It seems as if there is a margin both sides but nothing specified in the css.

```
.main-section.contact{
padding:85px 0;
}

.main-section.contact{
background: #ee0979; /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #ee0979 , #ff6a00); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to left, #ee0979 , #ff6a00); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */    
color: #fff;
}
```

Any suggestions, most welcome...

Comment: try: `html,body { margin: 0 }`

Comment: where will i insert that? margin: 0 is already specified in body in the css

Comment: Its already there. It works fine in all other sections, just the contact form section it seems to add this margin

Comment: Specifying `width:100%;` should fix this issue.

Comment: Tried that too, still the same...

Comment: didnt see the comments looks like you have already tried setting body tag to 0 px margin. would you able to post the css for rest of the elements this contact section might be nested in. code snippet would be great , i think its another element effecting your contact section layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find what was wrong with this, the div was outside the section in the html, soon as I corrected it the background did as expected.